# Is any group of people known by an animal name, specifically as 'bat'?

Tags: person-names

I'm wondering whether any specific people group (e.g. a certain nationality or a certain organization of people) can be referred to or is known by an animal name.

For example I know of people being referred to as "Kartoffel", so a type of food. "Eine deutsche Kartoffel" could refer to a German potato or a German person.

Is there something similar with animal names, specifically bats (Fledermaus)? If yes, why?

As a fictional example, I am imagining something like:
"Bankers are often called "Wölfe" in Germany because they tend to come in packs."

Edit:
Thank you all for your answers and explanations, I gained some interesting knowledge albeit not about bats :)

Comment: There are some nation-states (or empires) associated to certain animals. But this does not really refer to the people living there. You would speak of *der russische Bär*, but this would mean the state (or the empire, in 19th cent.), not the individual person from Russia.

Comment: "Heuschrecken" comes to mind. "Fledermäuse"? No.

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with German language specifically.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ one can understand that the OP asks for Fledermäuse, if one wishes. So, it is German language. Unfortunately, the answer is not quite interesting, though. So if off-topic, then it is by other reason

Comment: *Batman* and *Batwoman* fit. *Robin* doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **YES**

Fledermäuse is used as a term to describe people that are part of the goth/emo subculture. I'm still looking for a source, but I've heard that term used in that context.

Comment: Mir kräuseln sich die Nackenhaare. *Goth* oder **Emo**? ODER?

Comment: @Janka Im Zweifelsfall: "Punks" - Das passt immer.

Comment: @Janka Ich werfe dann zur Kräusel-Verstärkung auch noch den Namen in den Raum, den es zu meiner Schulzeit gab: *Grufti* :-)

Comment: Bei uns waren *Gruftis* noch alte Leute mit altmodischen Ideen.

Comment: I have accepted your answer despite lacking evidence, since it got a few upvotes

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any group being called after a kind of bats. In general there aren't that many groups for which an animal species is used as label.

#### Nationalites

**NOTE**: All of the following expressions are either pejorative or openly insulting!

I would have said that animals are not used for nations, for example, *Frösche* don't exist. The English frequently call the French *froggies* (and sometimes the French call themselves by this name, if there is some connection with the UK). In German they are often called *Schneckenfresser* (*snail eaters*) or *Froschfresser* (*frog eaters*).

There is only one exception - which I had never heard until quite recently, but which seems to be commonly known: *Inselaffen* (*island monkeys/apes*) for the English/British.

*Bears* and *dragons* can be used as synonyms for Russia and China, but not for the citizens of these countries.

#### "Organizations of people"

There are plenty of sports teams which provide an animal nickname. Examples:

- *Springböcke*: South African national team in rugby
- *Wölfe*: Members of VFL Wolfsburg (soccer)
- *Adler*: Members of Eintracht Frankfurt (soccer), Adler Mannheim (ice hockey)

Some other groups:

- *Bullen* (bulls; pejorative): police officers
- *Heuschrecken* (locusts; pejorative): certain kind of financial investors (as in English)
- *Nachteulen* (night owls): People who tend to (voluntarily) stay awake long in the evening.
- *Ameisen* (ants): In the context of an *Ameisenheer* (an army of workers in large factories), the individual workers.
- *Wale* (whales):

  - People who spend a lot of money in computer games (as in English; probably the English word is at least as widely used in German)
  - (pejorative) Label for obese people
- *Zecken* (ticks; pejorative): An expression that is used by right-wing extremists for certain people who are politically left
- *Haie* (ants; pejorative):

  - *Kredithaie* (loan sharks)
  - *Finanzhaie* (predatory actors in the financial sector)
  - *Miethaie* (predatory landlords)
  - (probably a few more)

Many animal names are popular nicknames (e.g.: Maus, Bärchen, Hase) or insults (e.g.: Esel, dumme Kuh, Schmutzfink).

**Edit:**

- Added *Haie* and another meaning for *Wale*.

Comment: Wal is also a derogatory term for obese people.

Comment: You forgot *Haie* (sharks) for people busy with grabbing other people's money in legal but unethical ways (--> *Finanzhai, Miethai*)

Comment: The opposite of the Eule (night owl) is a Lerche (lark).

Comment: @cbeleites: I had also thought of adding *Lerchen* and *Nachtigallen* (when I first wrote the answer), but I considered it too unlikely to encounter these words in their plural form. Admittedly, *Nachteulen* is not completely different.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: I'm surprised blutegel does not occur.

Comment: @Joshua: I have never heard of *Blutegel* applied to a group of person. One might add *Blutsauger* (for money lenders, tax authorities and the like), but that word encompasses mosquitoes, plenty other insects, certain bats, vampires etc.

Comment: @Joshua: Etymologically seemingly unrelated: Ekel. Still famous and occasionally in TV: [Ekel Alfred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eEuqwMpobY). Recommended if your German is sufficiently advanced and you want to see some German humour. (It was modeled on an American series, itself based on a British one.)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt: In English, bloodsucker is applied to lawyers per your example. Leech is occasionally applied to bankers, particularly corrupt financial advisors who give advise based on what yields the highest commission.

Answer (score 1):

The fans or players of the Spanish football club Fc Valencia were referred to as bats. It is because it is the towns symbol, so relatable to the citizens as well.
Not sure if it'll help you, but may be the closest you get.

Answer (score 0):

Police officers are colloquially called "Bullen" (bulls), which usually corresponds to the English word "cops".

According to Wikipedia, the etymology of that expression does not have anything to do with animals, though, but with the Dutch word "bol", which means "head" or "clever person".

Comment: To cite the OP: _"specifically bats (Fledermaus)"_

Answer (score 0):

No bats, sorry. :-(

As tofro points out, we often find *Heuschrecken*, locusts, referring to people who buy companies, sell everything out for money, and then move on. Probably what fits your banker example best.

We also find the not-quite-animal *Blutsauger*, bloodsuckers, used to refer to people who exploit others, especially to extract as much money as possible.

Then, on a different note, we have *Nachteulen*, night owls, people who like to have fun at night and consequentially sleep late into the day.